# Are black holes the source of power for rotating galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Just curious for the astronomers out there.  Something had to start the stars rotating around the center where the black hole is.

I assume for a planetary system it is the sun that drew in condensing matter but then that leaves the question of what starts these systems to rotate instead of just forming one large object.

There is probably a simple answer that answered this long ago.  My google searched found many theories on planet formation and solar system formation but no one addresses the question of what starts the rotation.

We do it with satellites that reach orbital velocity but I assume they travel in a parabolic arc and eventually begin to drop back into the earth but their speed balances the gravitational pull, but what starts this for solar systems and galaxies ?

Comment: In short, the residual angular momentum of whatever gas cloud the galaxy/star collapsed from.

Comment: I assume that applies for both cases .